# How to check if a certain pattern exists in a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

i was trying to implement a prolog predict that checks if a certain pattern say (x,m) exists in a list or m exists at the very end of the list and count the number of its occurrence i never get an answer to the number of times the pattern existed.why?

my attempt was :

```
    certainP([_,m],RESULT,W):-
    W is RESULT+1.
    certainP([x,m|T],START,RESULT):-
    RESULT is START+1,
    START is RESULT,
    certainP(T,START,RESULT).
```

Comment: What queries are you using, and what results do you expect from each?

Comment: @ScottHunter what do you mean by what queries am i using? either way im expecting the predicates to return the number of times x followed by m has occurred in the list

Comment: Queries: You type `certainP(` followed by what?  And what do you expect to happen?  Please give *examples*.

Comment: This predicate will fail if the second element of the list isn't an `m`; it will also fail if the length of the list is < 2.

Comment: @ScottHunter certainP (X,Y,Z) where X is a list for example [x,m,x,x,x,m,x] ,Y is the sum accumulator so basically Y will be zero at the very beginning and at the end the Z should equal 2 because that is the number of times" x,m "occurred in the list above so Z is Y+1 for the first x,m pair. 
[x,m,m,x,m,x,m] should output 3

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you describe:

```
certainP([],N,N).
certainP([_],N,N).
certainP([x,m|T],N,N2) :-
    N1 is N+1,
    certainP(T,N1,N2).
certainP([_|T],N,N2) :-
    certainP(T,N,N2).
```

This assumes that the middle argument is provided an initial numeric value in the query.